# clean the email column in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below

```
df <- data.frame(email=c("abc@gmail.com","def@gmail.com","ghi@gmail.com","jkl@gmail.com","mno@gmail.com","pqr@hotmail.com","st@u@live.com","vwx@gmail.com","yza@gmail.com","a.a.b@gmail.c.om",
                   "aac@gmail.com","abb@gmail.com","abc@gmail.com","cab@gmailcom","dfc@gmail.com"))
```

now i want to clean this column for below conditions: so i am trying to create a check like this i can add more checks i have than these 4 only...

1. Check if email is missing dot "."
2. Check if email has more than one "@"
3. Check if email has more than one "." before "@" and after"@"
4. Check if the domain have other mail than "gmail.com" like (hotmail.com, live.com) and so on....

so the output should be equal to....so that i will have checks to decide what to remove or update

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with `dplyr` and `stringr`. I splitted your third check into two columns.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

d <- df %>% 
  mutate(missing_dots = as.numeric(str_detect(email, "\\.", negate = TRUE)),
         more_than_1_at = as.numeric(str_detect(email, ".*@.*@.*|@{2,}")),
         more_than_1_dot_before = as.numeric(str_detect(email, ".*\\..*\\..*@.*")),
         more_than_1_dot_after = as.numeric(str_detect(email, ".*@.*\\..*\\..*")),
         no_gmail = as.numeric(str_detect(email, "@gmail.com", negate = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a combination of `dplyr` and `stringr`.  Note, I'm not exactly sure what you wanted to do with counting the dots, so I have made columns that are number of dots before and after the @.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(missing_dots = as.numeric(!str_detect(.$email, "\\.")),
  more_1_at = str_count(.$email, "@")-1, 
  dots_before = str_count(str_extract(.$email, ".*@"), "\\."), 
  dots_after = str_count(str_extract(.$email, "@.*"), "\\."), 
  from_gmail = as.numeric(str_detect(.$email, "gmail\\.com")))
#               email missing_dots more_1_at dots_before dots_after from_gmail
# 1     abc@gmail.com            0         0           0          1          1
# 2     def@gmail.com            0         0           0          1          1
# 3     ghi@gmail.com            0         0           0          1          1
# 4     jkl@gmail.com            0         0           0          1          1
# 5     mno@gmail.com            0         0           0          1          1
# 6   pqr@hotmail.com            0         0           0          1          0
# 7     st@u@live.com            0         1           0          1          0
# 8     vwx@gmail.com            0         0           0          1          1
# 9     yza@gmail.com            0         0           0          1          1
# 10 a.a.b@gmail.c.om            0         0           2          2          0
# 11    aac@gmail.com            0         0           0          1          1
# 12    abb@gmail.com            0         0           0          1          1
# 13    abc@gmail.com            0         0           0          1          1
# 14     cab@gmailcom            1         0           0          0          0
# 15    dfc@gmail.com            0         0           0          1          1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grepl`to match the variants and `ifelse` to assign `1`and `0`:

```
df$missing_dot <- ifelse(grepl("\\wcom", df$email), 1, 0)
df$more_than_1at <- ifelse(grepl("@.*@", df$email), 1,0)
df$more_than_1. <- ifelse(grepl("\\..*\\.", df$email), 1,0)
```

To include a column with the domain names, you can use `sub`and backreference `\\1`:

```
df$domain <- sub(".*@(.*)$", "\\1", df$email)
```

Result:

```
    df
              email missing_dot more_than_1at more_than_1.      domain
1     abc@gmail.com           0             0            0   gmail.com
2     def@gmail.com           0             0            0   gmail.com
3     ghi@gmail.com           0             0            0   gmail.com
4     jkl@gmail.com           0             0            0   gmail.com
5     mno@gmail.com           0             0            0   gmail.com
6   pqr@hotmail.com           0             0            0 hotmail.com
7     st@u@live.com           0             1            0    live.com
8     vwx@gmail.com           0             0            0   gmail.com
9     yza@gmail.com           0             0            0   gmail.com
10 a.a.b@gmail.c.om           0             0            1  gmail.c.om
11    aac@gmail.com           0             0            0   gmail.com
12    abb@gmail.com           0             0            0   gmail.com
13    abc@gmail.com           0             0            0   gmail.com
14     cab@gmailcom           1             0            0    gmailcom
15    dfc@gmail.com           0             0            0   gmail.com
```

Alternatively, if you want `0`and `1` for `gmail` v. other domains you can do this:

```
ifelse(grepl("gmail", df$email), 0, 1)
```